# starship cannot access/edit starship.toml

Tags: command-line, permissions, prompt

Whenever I try to import a starship.toml file by typing

```
starship preset tokyo-night -o ~/.config/starship.toml
```

I get the following error:

```
Error writing preset to file: Permission denied (os error 13)
```

I've looked at a bunch of posts detailing the same error, but none of the solutions have worked for me.
Additionally, copying the template from the website and pasting it into my own starship.toml file does not change anything.

I'm guessing this has something to do with folder permissions?
Some help would be appreciated

Edit:
Here's the output for `namei -lx ~/.config/starship.toml`

```
f: /home/caster/.config/starship.toml
Drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   home
drwxr-x--- caster caster caster
drwxrwxrwx caster caster .config
-rw-rw-r-- caster caster starship.toml
```